# How to remap <C-cc>?

Tags: key-bindings, quickfix

I want to map  to close `quickfixlist`, but when I do it will just send a message `Type :qa and press <Enter> to exit vim`.

I just do this `nnoremap <silent><C-cc> :cclose<CR>`

Comment: do you mean ctrl c then ctrl c?   or ctrl c then c

Comment: @Mass I mean I will hold the `CTRL` and press `c` twice

Comment: @zer09 the notation for that is still `<C-c><C-c>`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks it work

Comment: @zer09 It's not possible to hold `CTRL` and press `c` twice quickly and certainly `<C-cc>` is not something Vim understands. There are however some plugins that allow something similar, like the [tinymode](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2223) or [tinykeymap](https://github.com/tomtom/tinykeymap_vim) plugin

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt huh? Isn't that exactly like `<C-w><C-w>` where you hold control and tap `w`? I just tried `:nnoremap <C-c><C-c> :echo "hello"<cr>` and had no trouble

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Oh? It never occurred to me, that that would work. I thought one always had to press CTRL separately. But perhaps this is system specific.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt see `:help CTRL-W_w` and `:help 08.1` where I first learned this little trick; I don't think it's very different from, say, holding Command and pressing Tab repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

First your expression `<C-cc>` is not right like this, but guessing from the comments you want to remap `<C-c><C-c>`.

The problem with this is, that you cannot map  like this because this is the SIGINT signal (if I remember correctly).

It is possible though -> see `:help map-CTRL-C.`

So to remap `<C-c>` Vim has to be waiting for a key, so maybe try to use `<leader><C-c><C-c>` or something like this.

Comment: It works using `<C-c><C-c>` unless you press it slowly. Before I changed my config, `<C-c><C-c>` is a default mapping on one plugin I use, If I remember correctly it was `Coc`. Temporarly I use `<Leader>cc` but I want `C-cc` back because I can just press Ctrl with my side palm and press cc quickly.

Comment: in fact I was able to map `<C-c><C-c>`; the issue arises when vim is _busy_.